# Assign color to each side of a cube OpenFrameworks

Tags: c++, opengl, openframeworks

I'm looking for a way to draw a cube with a unique color per side. Currently, I'm using the following for the vertex and index data with w = width, h = height, and d = depth:

```
GLfloat vdata[8][3] = {
    {-w, -h, -d}, {-w, h, -d},
    {w, h, -d}, {w, -h, -d},
    {-w, -h, d}, {w, -h, d},
    {-w, h, d}, {w, h, d}
};

GLint indices[6][4] = {
    {3, 2, 1, 0},
    {3, 5, 4, 0},
    {3, 5, 7, 2},
    {0, 4, 6, 1},
    {1, 2, 7, 6},
    {5, 4, 6, 7}
};
```

I'm somewhat certain that I could just draw four vertices per face to achieve what I'm after, but I'd rather not take the performance hit of drawing all those extra vertices. Would a mapped texture make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 4 vertices per face is the correct way to do this. Why do you think that there will be a relevant "performance hit"? Texturing would very likely introduce a much larger performance loss.

Comment: This will be for a large number of cubes, so increasing the vertices per cube by 3x should decrease performance. I'll have to experiment with both options to know for sure.